# How can I scraping function values?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I want to scraped the website with app script.

The method I use now is to fetch the html first, then use the regex to filter what I need.
but it has a value that doesn't have what I want
I want to retrieve the number of comments.

-but it is

{{:count}} comment
[image]

-which what I want it should be

17 comment
[image]

I want to know what should I do?

[This is the site I want to scrape](https://pantip.com/topic/35241832)

the code I use in google sheet:

function scrapingweb() {

```
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
let headers = values[0];


let Link = headers.indexOf("header link from google sheet columb");

let titlename = headers.indexOf("title of web i want to scarping");



for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

    let rowData = values[i];
    let Link1 = rowData[Link]; // 
    var url = Link1

    var websiteContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

    var titleV = new RegExp(/(?<=title>)(.*)(?= - Pantip)/m);



    var titleText = titleV.exec(websiteContent);


    sheet.getRange(i + 1, titlename + 1).setValue(titleText);



}
```

}

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of the code used

Comment: you'll need a more advanced scrapper than just looking at html ... even scrapping code won't help with a dynamic site ... you'll need to actually **run** the code inside a **DOM** to make scrapping other peoples hard work more profitable for you

Comment: Maybe look at the network tab, it looks like client side template engine, maybe mustache.. As such it's likely getting the data via JSon, and that would be even easier to parse / query..

Comment: update: I followed all advice. Now i can fetch the values ​​i need i am using node js and puppeteer :)